# FormulaR1c1 to equal a newly created sheet

Tags: formula

I'm try to create a link to a newly created sheet, from an established/existing sheet.
The syntax seems to not read the action.

```
Sub Add_New_Property()
sheet_name_to_create = Sheet1.Range("g3").Value

Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = sheet_name_to_create
Sheets("Market Summary").Select
Range("P15").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='_     INPUT SHEET     _'!R115C6"
```

What I need is for the formula to link to the newly created sheet.  How do I do that.

Comment: What programming language is this?

Answer (score 0):

For the formula part please try:

```
= Sheet1.Range("g3").Value & R115C6
```